# passing array and user input using form

Tags: php

I am having difficulties dealing with form that passes an array. I have included 5 variables ("$a,$b,$c,$d,$e") in an array called $product, then I passed it to another frame use form along with an input that requires user typing in a value.
So there would be a array and an input being passed at the same time. So should I use "post" or "get"? It seems I should use "post" to pass the array, but the user input could only be passed via "get" right? Following is the code I had (the form is inside a table):

```
print "<td><form class=button action='bottom_right.php' method='post' target='bottom_right'>
        <input type='text' name='quantity'>
        <input type='hidden' name='product' value='<?php echo($product) ?>'>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary mb-2'>Add</button>
      </form></td>";
```

Besides, how could I retrieve the contents from another frame? Should that be something like below? How could I echo a single variable from the array?

```
<?php  
session_start();
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$product=$_POST['product'];
echo $quantity;
echo $product['a'];
echo $b;
?>
```

Looking forwards to your reply!
Cheers!

Comment: You can't have an open PHP tag and echo inside a string you're printing. And echoing an array won't really work either.

Comment: Little confused. What does this look like when viewing rendered source? `value='<?php echo($product) ?>`.

Comment: @ficuscr I would assume it looks like `value='<?php echo(Array()) ?>` (with an array to string conversion notice.)

Comment: Can you show how you create the `$product` array, some example values, and an example of what you're trying to get out of it when the form is submitted?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Hi! I tried "echo $product['a']" in the frame that sends the form, it works. But the same command doesn't work in the target frame. It seems the target frame doesn't retrieve the array.

Comment: Hi! Can you edit your question to show the output of `var_dump($product)`, please?

Comment: @Don'tPanic  It is something like this: "$product=array("a"=>$a,"b"=>$b,"c"=>$c,"d"=>$d,"e"=>$e); " I got these variables from mysql database, and need to put these variables in a new table under corresponding column in the target frame.

Comment: Okay. And are you expecting the user to enter a comma-separated list of values that correspond to a,b,c,d, and e?

Comment: Just a single integer from the user

Comment: @Don'tPanic the value of those variables have already been assigned from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Might be as simple as using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)/[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to transport the array.

`<input type='hidden' name='product' value='<?= implode(',', $product) ?>' />`

And then in PHP, you'll be looking for a string of concentated values under the `product` key.

```
<?php  

$quantity = (isset($_POST['quantity'])) $_POST['quantity'] ? : null;
$product = (isset($_POST['product'])) $_POST['product'] ? : '';
$productArray = explode(',', $product);

var_dump($productArray);
```

You could use POST or GET. You can convert the array to a string, using a delimiter to tokenize the parts, or you could use multiple hidden fields, one for each value in the array.

```
<!-- would probably POST if going this route...? -->
<input type='hidden' name='product[a]' value='<?= $product['a'] ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='product[b]' value='<?= $product['b'] ?>' />
```

Play around with it and use `var_dump($_POST);` to understand how the approaches modify what you receive.

Comment: I agree! Although there is still the problem of the whole HTML section that contains `$product` being a string output with `print`

Comment: The "frame" stuff is throwing me off.

Comment: Yeah, same here, I'm not sure what that's referring to in this context.

Comment: Actually I need to divide the whole page into three sections: left section, top_right section and bottom_section, each being used to displayed different contents

Comment: @张剑桥 Don't focus on the frame stuff so much. Complicates it unnecessarily I think. With iFrames you can just as well think of it as 3 separate pages.

Comment: I would personally look at multiple hidden inputs, assigning a specific value from `$products` to each. It is more explicit and will make it easier to ensure you get the POST data you expect on the targeted PHP script.